# Prevent scrolling when iPad keyboard is trigger by input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, ipad

Lets say I have an input with position fixed and wherever user scrolls, it would follow the user view. However, when an input is focus, it triggers the iPad keyboard, the input is jumping to the top and the window is scrolling to top as well. Is there anyway to prevent this happening and remaining the input wherever it is??

Comment: Is this really an issue? When the keyboard pops up the user would want to see what they are typing in. The input needs to be visible. Are you asking if this can be accomplished with the "scroll"?

Comment: The input will go back to the top instead of remaining at the same position.

Comment: if stays at the same position, won't it be hidden by the keyboard?

Comment: Well, only safari iPad has this issue. Other browsers do not have this problem so far on ipad.